# Wuapilib how to detect Definition Updates

Tags: windows-defender, automatic-updates

I need to know when an update, detecting with Wuapilib, is of type *Definition updates* (like Defender updates).
Using *ICategory* interface of Wuapilib I can get a property named *CategoryId* but I can't find documentation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ff357803(v=vs.85)

```
Classification Type Classification GUID
Application 5C9376AB-8CE6-464A-B136-22113DD69801
Connectors  434DE588-ED14-48F5-8EED-A15E09A991F6
CriticalUpdates E6CF1350-C01B-414D-A61F-263D14D133B4
DefinitionUpdates   E0789628-CE08-4437-BE74-2495B842F43B
DeveloperKits   E140075D-8433-45C3-AD87-E72345B36078
FeaturePacks    B54E7D24-7ADD-428F-8B75-90A396FA584F
Guidance    9511D615-35B2-47BB-927F-F73D8E9260BB
SecurityUpdates 0FA1201D-4330-4FA8-8AE9-B877473B6441
ServicePacks    68C5B0A3-D1A6-4553-AE49-01D3A7827828
Tools   B4832BD8-E735-4761-8DAF-37F882276DAB
UpdateRollups   28BC880E-0592-4CBF-8F95-C79B17911D5F
Updates CD5FFD1E-E932-4E3A-BF74-18BF0B1BBD83
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).